# LWC Reset Input Fields on Record Edit Form then Update Variables - Error e.forEach(...).then is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-recordeditform

I am trying to update variables immediately after I reset the Input Fields from my Record edit form.
Below is the Event Code from the JS. When it is run I receive the error - [e.forEach(...).then is not a function]

```
    resetFields(){
        const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
        inputFields.forEach( field => {
            field.reset();
        }).then(() => {
            this.pendingChanges = false;
            this.showConfirmationModal = false;
            this.showFooter = false;
            this.showEdit = false; 
            this.showSpinner = false;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For-each is a loop and do not return returns a promise that's why it's throwing error then is not defined.

Try resetting your variables after the for-each.

```
resetFields(){
        const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
        inputFields.forEach( field => {
            field.reset();
        });
            this.pendingChanges = false;
            this.showConfirmationModal = false;
            this.showFooter = false;
            this.showEdit = false; 
            this.showSpinner = false;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  
There are a lot of fields on my form and the reset can take a bit to complete.  
I only want the variables to update after the reset loop is complete.

Comment: For-each is synchronous you don't need to use promise here. JS will wait for the function to finish. Then move to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Having `forEach(something).then()` you're calling `then()` on the return value of
[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), but it returns `undefined`, that's why you get an error.

You could use `.then()` to handle a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), anyway in this case you should just remove it, since `forEach()` is not asynchronous.

```js
resetFields(){
    const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
    inputFields.forEach( field => {
        field.reset();
    });
    this.pendingChanges = false;
    this.showConfirmationModal = false;
    this.showFooter = false;
    this.showEdit = false; 
    this.showSpinner = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which is not an `Array`, so you have to convert it to an `Array` first:

```
const inputFields = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field')];
inputFields.forEach((field) => field.reset());
```

Where `[...variable]` iterates over `variable` that supports `Symbol.iterator` to produce an `Array` that you can use normally (`forEach`, `map`, etc).

Note that this is a synchronous process, so you don't need to "wait" for this function to end before resetting the other variables. However, if you do need that for some reason, use `async`/`await`:

```
async resetFields(){
  const inputFields = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field')];
  inputFields.forEach((field) => field.reset());
  await Promise.resolve(); // waits one render cycle
  this.pendingChanges = false;
  this.showConfirmationModal = false;
  this.showFooter = false;
  this.showEdit = false; 
  this.showSpinner = false;
}
```